# Rails application helper return if false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm writing a helper method to determine if current has any pending reviews to write. If there is a pending review, simply print a line in the view.
My helper is putting exactly the right stuff to the console, however I'm struggling with how to simply return it. In this scenario, current user has an id: 4.
My Code:

```
def review_pending
  gallery = current_user.galleries.first
  if gallery
    if gallery.permissions.accepted
      gallery.permissions.accepted.each do |p|

        return true if p.user.reviews.find_by_reviewer_id(!current_user)
        puts "already written review: #{p.user.reviews.find_by_reviewer_id(4)} - prints correctly"

      end
    end
  end
end
```

My goal: if there is a user from the list that current user has not yet reviewed return true.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: Why are you passing `!current_user` to `find_by_reviewer_id`? `!current_user` probably evaluates to `false`. Shouldn't you be passing an id instead?

Comment: Sorry, updating question.

Comment: Yes, what do you want to return? Declare somewhere `var = nil`, instead of returning `true`, assign `var` to the object you like and in your view check if you `var` is `nil` or not.

Comment: Thanks @Zozo will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your pointers!
I had forgotten/learned 2 things to make it work:
First, if nil is returned, ruby returns the last returned value which in my case was true (if gallery.permissions.accepted).
Secondly, I placed the "!" before current_user, and should have placed it before the entire line.
Corrected Code:

```
def review_pending
    gallery = current_user.galleries.first
    if gallery
        gallery.permissions.accepted.each do |p|
            return !p.user.reviews.find_by_reviewer_id(current_user.id)
        end
    end
    return false
end
```